# SQL Server Challenging questions - look for 1st buyer, 2nd/3rd buyers, 4th or more buyers

Tags: sql

I am assigned to write a SQL query to show the number of buyers who purchase a particular product in a certain data range and in a location.   I need to find the following:

1. 1st time buyer ever.
2. 2nd/3rd time buyers.
3. 4th or more time buyers.

I was able to get the first time ever buyers using the queries below; but unable to find the 2nd/3rd buyers, 4th or more buyers. How can I accomplish these things?

```
DECLARE @from_dt        datetime
DECLARE @Day_End_dt     datetime

SET @from_dt =     '10/01/2010'
SET @Day_End_dt =  '12/29/2010'


select count(B.buyer_id) as California_1st_time_buyer
from
--LIST OF ALL BUYERS AND FIRST PURCHASED DATE THRU END OF DATE RANGE (10/1/98 - 12/28/10)
(select distinct buyer_id, min(purchased_date_time) as First_timer
from product_details
where purchased_date <@Day_End_dt
group by buyer_id
)A,
--LIST OF CALIFORNIA BUYERS AND FIRST PURCHASED DATE IN DATE RANGE (12/1/10 - 12/28/10)
(select distinct buyer_id, min(purchased_date_time) as First_timer_ca_in_date_range
from product_details
where purchased_date >=@from_d
and purchased_date <@Day_End_dt
and location = 'CA'
group by buyer_id
)B
where A.buyer_id = B.buyer_id
and A.First_timer = B.First_timer_ca_in_date_range



Input sample:
purchased_date_time     purchased_date      buyer_id
12/7/2010 12:30:00 PM       12/7/2010       5627242
--------------------------------------------------------------------
12/9/2010 4:30:00 PM         12/9/2010       9231374
12/19/2010 11:30:00 AM     12/19/2010      9231374
--------------------------------------------------------------------
12/9/2010 12:10:00 AM       12/9/2010       8061088
12/15/2010 5:00:00 PM       12/15/2010      8061088
12/21/2010 6:00:00 PM       12/21/2010      8061088
--------------------------------------------------------------------
12/1/2010 12:30:00 PM       12/1/2010       2288101
12/12/2010 6:30:00 PM       12/12/2010      2288101
12/27/2010 7:30:00 PM       12/27/2010      2288101
12/28/2010 6:30:00 PM       12/28/2010      2288101
--------------------------------------------------------------------
12/9/2010 10:45:00 AM       12/9/2010       2510454
12/16/2010 9:45:00 PM       12/16/2010      2510454
12/19/2010 4:19:00 AM       12/19/2010      2510454
12/22/2010 7:05:00 AM       12/22/2010      2510454
12/29/2010 2:30:00 AM       12/29/2010      2510454
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Output sample:
1st buyers =5 --count buyer_id who purchased the product first time ever in date range (12/1/10 - 12/28/10)

2nd/3rd buyers =7 --count buyer_id who purchased the product 2nd/3rd time in date range (12/1/10 - 12/28/10)

4th or more buyers =3  --count buyer_id who purchased the product 4th time or more in date range (12/1/10 - 12/28/10)
```

Please note these buyers are only from the date range mentioned above. Suppose if a buyer had three purchases prior to 12/1/2010 and they purchased again on 12/1/2010, they would be considered as a 4th time buyer.

Comment: Could you provide which DBMS you are using and sample input/output to add clarity?

Comment: I am using MS SQL server 2000/2005/2008. Thanks,

Comment: Is the first time buyer ever? or the first time buyer in that date range?. Besides, you say you were able to get the first time buyer, but in your query you are doing a COUNT of the buyer, not getting the buyer id

Comment: yes, first time buyers in that data range. Sorry for the confusion, i was counting the buyers. Thanks

Comment: "I am using MS SQL server 2000/2005/2008. " - really? No, really?

Comment: Another question, do the 2nd, 3rd and 4th buyers have to be different buyers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't entirely understand what you want to do. If you could update the question with Table structure, a couple of sample rows and the expected output it would help.

Anyway, here is an attempt :)

The following query should give you a list of buyers that made four or less purchases. It isn't clear if you just wanted to count the purchases or if you need the actual purchase dates too, so I added the dates as well (for the first 4 purchases). If a buyer made only 1 purchase, the row would show NULL in purchase 2/3/4 columns.

If you want to include a range of dates or filter by location, those conditions would go in the inner select.

```
select buyer_id
      ,count(*) as purchases
      ,max(case when purchase_no = 1 then purchased_date end) as purchase_1
      ,max(case when purchase_no = 2 then purchased_date end) as purchase_2
      ,max(case when purchase_no = 3 then purchased_date end) as purchase_3
      ,max(case when purchase_no = 4 then purchased_date end) as purchase_4
  from (select buyer_id
              ,purchased_date
              ,row_number() over(partition by buyer_id
                                     order by purchased_date) as purchase_no
          from product_details
       )
 where purchase_no <= 4
group by buyer_id;
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Ronnis, I have edited my question with input and output sample. I am testing your query now. Thanks very much

Comment: Thanks, Ronnis. The row_number part is very useful.

Comment: @joe, I don't understand how "2nd/3rd buyers" = 7? You have 5 distinct buyers in your sample data. 1 who bought the product 2 times (id 9231374), one who bought the product 3 times (id 8061088). I also don't understand how "4th or more buyers" = 3? There are only 2 buyers that have bought the product 4 or more times (id 2288101 and id 2510454).

Answer (score 0):

This query will provide the buyer_id and number of purchases in the date range:

```
DECLARE @from_dt datetime
DECLARE @Day_End_dt datetime
SET @from_dt =     '10/01/2010'
SET @Day_End_dt =  '12/29/2010' 

SELECT [buyer_id],COUNT([buyer_id]) AS purchases_in_period
  FROM [product_details]
  WHERE purchased_date_time between @from_dt and @Day_end_dt
  -- OPTIONAL LOCATION FILTER
  -- AND [location] = 'CA'
  GROUP BY [buyer_id]
GO
```

If you use this as a nested query you can count the `buyer_id` values with a given number of `purchases_in_period`.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally approach this as a union of separate queries.

```
      select buyer from T,  1 as FirstTimeBuyer, 0 as SecondTimeBuyer, 0 as thirdtimebuyer
      where date is in the specified range
      group by buyer having count(t.id) = 1
      UNION
       select buyer from T,  0 as FirstTimeBuyer, 1 as SecondTimeBuyer, 0 as thirdtimebuyer
      where date is in the specified range
      group by buyer having count(t.id) = 2
      UNION
       select buyer from T,  0 as FirstTimeBuyer, 0 as SecondTimeBuyer, 1 as thirdtimebuyer
      where date is in the specified range
      group by buyer having count(t.id) = 3
```